# How can I define a date-time-index for a lengthy database in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, python-datetime

I am struggling with setting a datimeindex with monthly data since year 1 AD, whereas I do not find the same problem with the same data with a shorter time span, say 1950 to 2020

**This code works**

```py
co2data_monthly = pd.read_excel(path to my data)
co2data_monthly = co2data_monthly[co2data_monthly['year']>=1950]
dtindex = np.arange('1950-01-01', '2020-04-01', dtype='datetime64[M]')
co2data_monthly = co2data_monthly.set_index(dtindex)
```

**This code does not work**

```py
co2data_monthly = pd.read_excel(path to my data)
co2data_monthly = co2data_monthly[co2data_monthly['year']>=1950]
dtindex = np.arange('0001-01-01', '2020-04-01', dtype='datetime64[M]')
co2data_monthly = co2data_monthly.set_index(dtindex)
```

So when I am trying to defined January 1st of 1 A.D. I get the following error message
`Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00`

**What I want...**

My final output should be my database with a monthly date time index since year 1 to year 2020

Answer (score 0):

A pandas datetime is stored as an positive integer number of *time units* (nanoseconds by default) since a particular *origin* date (default: Unix epoch, ie 01.01.1970).

Since 01.01.0001 is way before Unix epoch, you get that error. Instead specify the Julian calender epoch (January 1, 4713 BC), and use D=Daily as the unit.

You can skip the arange when creating the index, and just use [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead. Something like the below code, which assumes that your dates are in the "year column" (might not be correct). You may also need to specify the date format explicitly using `format`.

```
...
co2data_monthly['time'] = pandas.to_datetime(co2data_monthly['year'], unit='D', origin='julian')
co2data_monthly = co2data_monthly.set_index('time')
```